# How to convert .class in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following statement in Java that I need to convert to Scala:

```
MyClass myClass = object.method(MyClass.class);
```

Note that MyClass is a Java class, and object.method a Java method.

My attempt is

```
val myClass = object.method(MyClass.class)
```

however I get an error in `MyClass.class` saying `identifier expected but 'class' found`. How to convert this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala equivalent of Java .class is classOf method

Try

```
object.method(classOf[MyClass])
```